# SpriteKit: SKPhysicsJointPin allows node to penetrate chain of nodes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have 10 `SKSpriteNode`s that are connected via `SKPhysicsJointPin`s. Together, they form a chain (each node is a chain-link image and each node has a `physicsBody`).

There are also some balls that bounce around and interact with the chain.

Desired behavior: The balls should never penetrate the chain.

Actual behavior: The chain-link joints allow too much leeway, and the balls go *through* the chain. To be clear, I'm not talking about tunneling -- the balls don't go through the nodes, themselves. Instead, the chain-nodes sort of move aside and the balls go through the opening.

The code to create the chain-links (please assume that all variables are defined and that the positioning of each node is correct. Hopefully you can see what's going on here):

```
let chains = mainData.getLevelChains()
let bodyA = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "chainLink.png")
                    
bodyA.size = CGSize(width: chainLinkWidth, height: chainLinkHeight)
                    
bodyA.position = CGPoint(x:chains[i].leftAnchorPosition.x + CGFloat(halfChainLinkWidth) + (chainWidth * (0.1 * CGFloat(j))), y: chains[i].leftAnchorPosition.y)
                    
bodyA.name = "body"
                    
bodyA.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: bodyA.texture!, size: CGSize(width: chainLinkWidth, height: chainLinkHeight))
                    
bodyA.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypes.chain.rawValue
bodyA.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypes.ball.rawValue
                    
addChild(bodyA)

let joint = SKPhysicsJointPin.joint(withBodyA: previousChainLink.physicsBody!, bodyB: bodyA.physicsBody!, anchor: CGPoint(x: Double(previousChainLink.position.x)+halfChainLinkWidth, y: Double(previousChainLink.position.y)))
                    
scene?.physicsWorld.add(joint)
```

**Question: What can I do to ensure that the chain maintains its structural integrity so the balls never go through the chain?**

Comment: Maybe extend the physics bodies of the chain links so that they're bigger along the length direction of the links and overlap a little more to cover the gaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I solved the problem by setting the `mass` of the chain-links to a value slightly greater than that of the balls.

```
ball.physicsBody?.mass = 5.0
```

```
chainLink.physicsBody?.mass = 6.0
```